# Video Player class for in-memory video

Tags: c#, video, video-streaming, vlc, windows-media-player

I was looking for a way to reproduce a video in a C# application.
I found tons of tutorials for reproducing a local file ("C://users/com/Desktop/video.mp4") with various players like VLC or Windows media player embedded on a C# application.
The problem is that on my application the video will arrive from a TCP connection so now I have 2 ways:

1. write the byte[] that will arrive on the file system and than reproduce that "temporary file"
2. found a Video class in wihch I can put the data stream of the video file and a player that can reproduce that class.
   In other words I'm looking for a class that can wrap a mp4 (or a mpeg or an avi no matter what...) and a player that can reproduce that class without touching the file system.

PS: I don't want a streaming because I don't want buffering problems and for my project I prefer to send the entire data and then start the reproduction.

Comment: Just google: c# winfotms video player

Comment: You could take a look at the Accord Framework, it has nuget packages. http://accord-framework.net/  -  there is a video capture example there  -  https://github.com/accord-net/framework/wiki/Sample-applications#screencast-capture-lite

Comment: sorry what do you mean with "nuget packages?".

Comment: The problem is that the most of the project i saw there doesn't have audio support.
Besides, are you sure there is a class that wrap a video inside 
 and reproduce it without touching file system after load?